# Photo gallery for Blogspot blog

Tags: website-features, blog, blogger, thumbnail, photo-gallery

I don't think this is entirely possible, but here we go:

I have a friend who has a **Blogspot** blog. He has posts with text, posts with videos and posts with **photos**... and he was wondering if there's any way to turn the posts which are just photos into a **thumbnail gallery** screen on his blog.

So for example, let's say he has 20 photo posts on his blog with the label *Skiing Holiday 2009* (horrible example, I know). Is there a way of having a post created for his blog that displays those photos as thumbnails, linking through to their full size versions?

I just don't think it's possible, but I'm really hoping someone will be able to offer a solution (or even a place where I could find a solution).

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello good guitar songs lover (yeah, Django Reinhardt rocks).

I don't think you can implement that gallery directly on blogspot. I have 4 blogs (don't ask me why so much) on blogspot, and I've never found such feature but I got an idea.

Your friend can use flickr to make his galleries, and then [use its galleries feature](http://www.flickr.com/help/galleries/) to embed into blogspot.

The problem is the limit to galleries. Only 18 pics per gallery can be added. You can [search an app](http://www.flickr.com/services/) to do that though.

There are other possibilities on flickr also that you can explore and check if fits, like sets, collections, mosaics... I really think it worth a try.

**EDIT**

First you need to create a gallery as indicated on the link I passed, OR create a set (it is really easy). Then go viewing the created gallery or set.

Galleries will have a "Grab the embed HTML" box. Just copy that HTML and post it in blog post body. Done.

For sets, you have the option to see a slideshow. On upper right corner you will see a box with the same option "Grab the embed HTML". Repeat the process to embed a slideshow into blog post. This option also can be used with galleries, tags, and any kind of organizing options available from flickr.

Comment: +1 This sounds very promising! Can you explain to me how you go about embedding a Flickr gallery in Blogspot? Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing. Check my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Google Blogger does not have such features.  You could write a lot of complex Javascript and ajax to actually parse each post and create a thumbnail for each one that does not have text.

I think your best bet is to take advantage of the tagging feature.
Tag posts that belong in gallery with the word "gallery"

then simply make a link in the template to do a search by that tag.

http://blog.yoursite.com/search/label/Gallery

Comment: Yep, but this is a last resort for my friend, I think. Thanks for your answer, though.

Comment: its not sexy, but it works.  I use blogger and prefer it over wordpress.  You can do great things with the design, but the functionality is poor.  There is a google group for blogger that can give you more detailed technical assistance.